# Prove that a functor creates limits

Tags: category-theory

Let $F:\textbf{C}\to\textbf{D}$ be a functor. How do we prove that $F$ creates limits for a particular class of diagrams if $\textbf{C}$ has those limits and $F$ prserves them and $F$ reflects isomorphisms?

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to prove that $F$ reflects limits, ie. that if $π = (π_i : C → C_i)_i$ is a cone in $\mathbf C$, and $Fπ$ is the limiting cone, then so is $π$ itself. To do this, take the limit $(λ_i : L → C_i)_i$ of the diagram in question and factor $π$ through it as $π = f ∘ λ$ (ie. $π_i = f ∘ λ_i$ for each $i$). You can't prove directly that $f$ is iso, but since $F$ is conservative, you can just show that $Ff$ is, and that's easy. $Fπ$ is the limiting cone by assumption, $Fλ$ is too because $F$ preserves limits, and $Ff$ has to be the unique isomorphism $g: FC → FL$ which satisfies $Fπ = g ∘ Fλ$.

(This is assuming that you're using the definition of created limit such as the one on [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/schreiber/show/created%20limit). If you use a stronger definition, such as the one on Wikipedia with the uniqueness condition, then this isn't true as stated. For a trivial counterexample you can take the (equivalence) functor $F : 2_\mathrm{ind} → 1$ from the two object indiscrete category to the one object one, and note that the unary product isn't uniquely lifted.)

Comment: Why is it enough to prove that $F$ reflects limits? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Jt3Best Sure, just add the exact definition of creating limits you're working with to the question, and I'll try to be more specific.

Comment: For any class of diagrams $K:J\to C$ valued in $C$, a functor $F:C\to D$ creates limits if whenever $FK:J\to D$ has a limit in $D$, there is some limit cone over $FK$ that can be lifted to a cone over $K$, and moreover $F$ reflects the limits in the class of diagrams.

Comment: @Jt3Best: Ok, then you still need a limiting cone in $\mathbf D$ that can be lifted to a cone in $\mathbf C$. But $Fλ$ as above works.

Comment: How exactly would I do this?

Comment: @Jt3Best: $Fλ$ is a limiting cone over $FK$ because $F$ preserves limits, and $λ$ is by definition its lift to a cone over $K$.